# Euclidean distance between time series in Python

Tags: time-series

While thinking about similarity between two time series, one can use [DTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) to approach the issue. There is a Python package for that [mlpy](http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/docs/3.4/dtw.html).

It is also [said](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15812/check-similarity-between-time-series) to compare time series via simple euclidean distance.

Is there a Python package to this?

Comment: Google: "Euclidean Distance python" results in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy and in http://www.codehamster.com/2015/03/09/different-ways-to-calculate-the-euclidean-distance-in-python/

Comment: Start by telling us what time-intervals the two series actually represent? And have same length?

Answer (score 6):

This only makes sense if you look at the time series as vectors with same length. In that case, there is no need for a package. Just use, for example, 
`numpy.linalg.norm(a-b)`.